# Multiple Prepared Statements or a Batch

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

My question is very simple and in the title. Google and stack overflow are giving me nothing so I figured it was time to ask a question.

I am currently in the process of making an sql query for when users register to my site. I have ALWAYS only used prepared statements b/c the extra coding in callable statements, and the performance hit of regular statements are both turn offs. However this query is causing me to think of possible alternatives to my previous one size fits all (prepared statements) ways.

This query has a total of 4 round trips to the database. The steps are

1. Insert a user into the database, get back the generated key (their user id) within a result set.
2. Take the user id and insert a row into the album table. Get back a generated key (album id)
3. Take the album id and insert a row into the images table. Get back a generated key (image id)
4. Take the image id and update the user tables current default column with the image id

**Aside:** For anyone interested in the way I am getting the keys back after my inserts it is with `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` and you can read a great article about this here - [IBM Article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jdbcnew/)

So anyway I'd like to know if the use of 4 round trip (but cacheable) prepared statements is okay or if I should go with batched (but not cacheable) statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JDBC batch statements let you reduce the number of roundtrips under a condition that there is no data dependency among the rows that you are inserting or updating. Your scenario fails this condition, because the changes are dependent on each other's data: statements 2 through 4 must pick up an ID from the prior statement 1 through 3.

On the other hand, four round-trips is definitely suboptimal. That is why scenarios like yours call for stored procedures: you can put all this logic into a `create_user_proc`, and return the user ID back to the caller. All insertions from 1 to 4 would happen inside your SQL code, letting you manage ID dependencies in SQL. You would be able to call this stored procedure in a single roundtrip, which is definitely faster, especially if you process multiple user registrations per minute.

Comment: Thank you. I'll take your advice. Do you happen to have a link where I can get some instruction on what you are telling me to do? Especially how to get the generated key and move on to the next table? I am using mysql.

Comment: And should you pretty much always use stored procedures from a purely performance standpoint? Wouldn't it always be faster then prepared statements or regular statements?

Comment: @gmustudent You can learn about stored procedures in MySQL by looking at the tutorials [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure-tutorial.aspx). The syntax is not that complex - in you case, you'll have four inserts, and use [`last_inserted_id()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) function.

Comment: @gmustudent In addition to purely performance reasons offered through reducing the number of roundtrips, stored procedures let you move the logic of data manipulation and retrieval to the RDBMS side. Using SPs for encapsulation of logic is a matter of preference, though.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight you are mistaken about in your first assumption. All inserts/updates doesn't not work with only one table. The code `Statement stmt1 = connection.createStatement(); addBatch("insert into one_table values (1)"); addBatch("insert into some_other_table values (2)"); executeBatch();` correctly shows `130524 10:59:09 15087 Query insert into one_table values (1);insert into some_other_table values (2)` in the query log.

Comment: @AndreasWederbrand That's nice to know. I am nearly certain that I ran into the first limitation some time ago, but I can't recall when and what driver it was (I've been out of Java world for 5+ years now). Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

I would advice to write one Stored Proc doing all this four operation and passing the all the required params from application (to stored proc) at once and there in stored proc, you can get the generated keys for resultset

Answer (score 1):

To increase performance and reduce database round trips, I agree with dasblinkenlight and ajduke - stored procedures will achieve this.

But, it this really a performance bottleneck in your application?

- How often do users register on your site?
- Compare this to how often information is *read* from these tables (once per page access?)

If information in these tables are being read thousands of times more than being written via new registrations, then it might not be worth going for the stored procedure approach.

Why you might not want to use stored procedures and stick to prepared statements:

- not as portable as using prepared statements (a different syntax/language for each database, some simpler databases don't even support them)
- will not work with ORM solutions such as JPA* - you mentioned using PreparedStatements directly so this probably does not apply to you, at least not now but it might limit you later on if you wanted to use ORM in the future

*JPA 2.1 might actually [support stored procedures](https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/jpa_2_1_early_draft), but as of writing it has not yet been released.